# Cypress running in parallel on AWS recording to old run

Tags: cypress, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am running cypress in a pipeline that has 2 build actions (that use the same codebuild) for running in parallel. After I manually initiate the pipeline, it will pass with a success. The problem is that the test suite isn't ran. It lists the link to cypress dashboard but it links to an older run and not a new one. I am using --ci-build-id $CODEBUILD_INITIATOR per the cypress documentation. Anyone have an idea why I am not getting unique runs every time the pipeline is ran?

Comment: I think parallelization in cypress needs at least 2 physical machines and that is why you cannot do it. If you have a plan that includes parallelization maybe you should ask the cypress support.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was due to the buildspec not being setup correctly to run machines in parallel. The the batch build configuration was not set in Codebuild. Quite simple really.

---

Originally the pipeline just ran two instances of the same codebuild.      The first times it was ran by initiating the pipeline manually it worked and reported fine through cypress dashboard.   Changing the buildspec to run a buildlist solved this problem. I was too hung up on following the buildmatrix example that was given in the cypress documentation.

---

[image: buildspec]